# Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

when running some command in magento 2.4.3 such as "setup: upgrade" an error is generated in elasticsearch how can I solve this? I'll put pictures below.

[image]

Comment: You mean before setup:upgrade elasticsearch is running and status is active? Because now I see elasticsearch is down. Also what version of elasticsearch you using?

Comment: I meant that it seems to work, however when I run a magento command like setup:upgrade it stops working and stays that way.

Comment: So what Elasticsearch version you are using?

Comment: i use version 7.9

Comment: What version are set in admin configuration? Should be Elasticsearch7.

Comment: yes i set to elasticsearch 7.

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue of elastic search connection.
to test it just goto admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search  then you can see elastic search details like host and port.

so just run "curl -XGET [host]:[port]" and you will able to identify that connection is not working or not

Comment: yes it is working, however if I run setup:upgrade it stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to restart Elasticsearch first:
For example on Ubuntu:

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

If it still not working, try to debug with error message shown on the terminal.

Comment: it to run elasticsearch every time setup:upgrade is run. ):

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your elasticsearch is broken in some way. Could try to reinstall it. Or you could use https://github.com/duydo/evm . Very good tool, can switch Elasticsearch version if required. Also easy to run. Remove your current ES and install this one. Try to use it. If same problem, try to look for custom modules, that maybe try to reindex something to elasticsearch. Disable it and try again.